# How to transacting with a smart contract using web3j in Android?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3j

i used web3j to [Transacting with a smart contract](https://docs.web3j.io/transactions.html#transacting-with-a-smart-contract).
this is my Contract function which i want to intertact with.

```
function usersRegister(string _id, string _password){
    Equipment e = equipments[msg.sender];
    e.users[e.usersNum++] = User({id: _id, password: _password, registerTime: now});
}
```

and this is my code in Android using web3j

```
Web3j web3j = Web3jFactory.build(new HttpService(url));
EthGetTransactionCount ethGetTransactionCount = web3j.ethGetTransactionCount(
                        equipmentAddress, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).sendAsync().get();
                BigInteger nonce = ethGetTransactionCount.getTransactionCount();
BigInteger gasPrice = Contract.GAS_PRICE;
BigInteger gasLimit = Contract.GAS_LIMIT;

List<Type> inputParameters = new ArrayList<>();
Type usersId = new Utf8String(_usersId);
Type usersPassword = new Utf8String(_usersPassword);
inputParameters.add(usersId);
inputParameters.add(usersPassword);
Function function = new Function("usersRegister",
                        inputParameters,
                        Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
String functionEncoder = FunctionEncoder.encode(function);
Transaction transaction = Transaction.createFunctionCallTransaction(
                        equipmentAddress, nonce, gasPrice,
                        gasLimit, contractAddress, new BigInteger("0"),
                        functionEncoder);
EthSendTransaction transactionResponse =
                 web3j.ethSendTransaction(transaction).sendAsync().get();
```

but i get "null" in `transactionResponse.getTransactionHash()`

someone know what's wrong with my code?thx for help :x

Comment: Transactions take some time to validate. It might take up to a few minutes. Are you doing your transaction in the background?

Comment: I created an example project, how to read and write to smart contracts. You can find the code on [github](https://github.com/noev/Android-Ethereum-Hello-World/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/noev/greeter/MainActivity.java) and some explanation [here](https://blog.jayway.com/2017/08/23/interacting-with-ethereum-smart-contracts-from-android/)

Answer (score 0):

please check the credential. because the the key file in keystore folder is wrong file. an account of credential have to be registered in eth.accounts[] list.
I solved the problem. ^^